# Select XElement witch have numeric value using XPath

Tags: xpath

I have this xml file, I want to extract all xelement having number value in it attibute using XPath

```
<XtraSerializer version="1.0" application="TabbedView">
  <property name="Items" iskey="true" value="5">
    <property name="Item1" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Name">5d297655-eee4-4ab5-baa7-7d12964ac1ad</property>
      <property name="TypeName">Document</property>
    </property>
    <property name="Item3" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Name">48575907</property>
      <property name="TypeName">DockingContainer</property>
    </property>
    <property name="Item4" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Index">0</property>
      <property name="Name">63403262</property>
      <property name="TypeName">DockingContainer</property>
    </property>
  </property>
</XtraSerializer>
```

My result must be:

```
<property name="Name">48575907</property>
<property name="Name">63403262</property>
```

I use this syntax //property[text()=number]
in the tester https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

But it give me NO MATCH!

What is wrong with the syntax I used to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPATH that returns `property` node with integer value that not equal to `0`

```
//property[number(text()) != 0]
```

if you want to fetch zero-value also:

```
//property[number(text()) != 0 or number(text()) = 0]
```

Comment: Thank you, but using the tester it give me : Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of number() (text(""), text(""), text(""), ...)

Comment: @naourez did you try it somewhere except XPATH tester? Also it works fine in [this](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) tester

Comment: Yes I tried in c# code but it give me all property witch didn't contain 0, but I need only numeric values

Comment: @naourez , how about more specific expression `//property[@name="Name" and number(text()) != 0]` or ``//property[@name="Name" and number(text()) != "NaN"]``?

Comment: my xml file is more long than the example that I indicate. the property name contain many values as string and others as numeric values, that's why I need general rules without indicating string values

Comment: you are right using your tester //property[@name="Name" and number(text()) != 0] it give the right answer, but in my c# it didn't

Comment: @naourez , Oh... OK. Last try:) Is it working `//property[@name="Name" and number(text()) castable as xs:integer]`?

Comment: unfortenatly in my code c# it catch an exception. So I decided to select all xelement having name="Name"